# Async Viewmodel constructor initializing data

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I've followed the pattern defined at [Async OOP](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) to create a view model which reads data from 2 sources. However, when I attempt to setup `CollectionViewSource` and Filters for the collection I get an exception `Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.` or when filtering the data I get the following exception `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

The properties are defined as follows

```
    public NotifyTaskCompletion InitializationNotifier{ get; set; }
    public Task Initialization => InitializationNotifier.Task;
```

The viewmodel constructor defines the `InitializationNotifier` as follows:

```
    InitializationNotifier = new NotifyTaskCompletion(InitializeAsync());
```

The task is defined as below:

```
    private async Task InitializeAsync()
    { 
      var aDataSource = await Task.Run(() => ADataSource.Get(1, 2));
      var bDataSource = await Task.Run(() => new BDataSource(1, 2);
      PrepareData(aDataSource, bDataSource); // creates List<T> for different categories
      SetupCollections(); // Creates Observable collections from List<T>
      SetupCVSAndFilters();    // Creates CollectionViewSource for different categories
    }

    private void SetupCollections()
    {
        AStars = new ObservableCollection<IAEntity>(m_aStars);
        BStars = new ObservableCollection<IAEntity>(m_bStars);
    }
    // Setup Collectionview source and Filters
    // Get an exception: 
    // Additional information: Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject.
    private void SetupCVSAndFilters()
    {
        AStarsCVS = new CollectionViewSource { Source = AStars };
        BStarsCVS = new CollectionViewSource { Source = BStars };
        AStarsCVS.View.Filter = FilterCompareData;
        BStarsCVS.View.Filter = FilterCompareData;
    }
```

The view/viewmodel works well without using `Async`/`Task`, but the fetches from the datasources are time-consuming(`PInvoke`s) and I have multiple tabs which read different data and I'd appreciated pointers to help me understand where I'm going wrong with the usage of `Task`/`Async`

Comment: If you're really willing to understand what's going on here, you can install Concurrency Visualizer (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ConcurrencyVisualizer2017). You can use it with a simple API (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ConcurrencyVisualizer/), with which you can mark sections in your code and observe on which threads they are executed (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hh755853.aspx). It's really cool.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `Task.Run()` a new thread is created. The exceptions you're getting have to do with your threads trying to access each other in ways they're not supposed to. I don't think I can see where it's going wrong just by the code you've provided, but I can tell you that in WPF, threads can access the objects of other threads using [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

It also looks like you may not be getting the benefits of asynchronous programming that you're looking for. Having two `await` statements one after the other like that means the first task will complete before the second one even starts. I think you want [`Task.WaitAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Why downvoted? That's a correct answer - it's not enough code to say what's going on, as we don't know if the view model constructor was called from a UI thread.

Comment: @swiszcz I did not downvote it, I agree  that I could have provided more code. The view/viewmodel is a tab content and the viewmodel constructor is indeed called from a UI thread.